# Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.myapp.webapp.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f5a3c0.configureContentNegotiation

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a small project with `hibernate`+`jpa`,`Spring`, `Spring MVC`(without `SpringBoot`). Now I'm trying to add `Spring Security`.

`UserDetailsServiceImpl.class`:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    Service<Account> accountService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setMail(mail);
        Account foundedAccount = accountService.readByObj(account);
        if (foundedAccount == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Account not found");
        }
        return new User(foundedAccount.getMail(), foundedAccount.getPassword()
                , true, true, true, true,
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + foundedAccount.getRole())));
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig.class`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.webapp.config"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/account/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("mail")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()

                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("mail", "password", "id")
                .and()

                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me");
                //.

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

    }
}
```

`SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class`:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {


}
```

`WebConfig.class`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.service.config",
"com.myapp.webapp"
} )

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountController.class);

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(accountInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/account", "/editAccount", "/editSecurity", "/editMainInfo");
        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(entityManagerInViewInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources ").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/jsp ").addResourceLocations("/jsp/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserValidationInterceptor accountInterceptor() {
        return new UserValidationInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor entityManagerInViewInterceptor() {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor = new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor();
        openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor;
    }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

and `AppInit.class`:

```
public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebConfig.class,
                SecurityConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
       return new Class<?>[]{
                WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

After installing and deploying project in `Maven` trowing exception:

```
10-Jan-2018 18:54:33.562 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-8] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:  
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT]] 
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.myapp.webapp.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f5a3c0.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at com.myapp.webapp.config.WebServletConfiguration.onStartup(WebServletConfiguration.java:28)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.myapp.webapp.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f5a3c0.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager]: Factory method 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.myapp.webapp.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f5a3c0.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.myapp.webapp.config.WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f5a3c0.configureContentNegotiation(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer;)V 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.configureContentNegotiation(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.configureContentNegotiation(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcContentNegotiationManager(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:368)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3318d161.CGLIB$mvcContentNegotiationManager$25(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3318d161$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3906aa77.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3318d161.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: did you try to import SecurityConfig class to your WebConfig class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.In spring base project it is better to import configuration class to WebConfig class witch extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` or `webmvcconfigurationsupport` .

2.And in ServletInitializer class it is enough to make webConfig class as a root 
config class.

```
public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
       return new Class<?>[]{

        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

and before this you must import you security config class to webApp config class.

```
@Import({SecurityConfig.class/*,and other config classes*/})
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.service.config",
"com.myapp.webapp"
} )

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
//other bean stuff
}
```